# converting a c# linq statement into vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

i have a code in C# that uses linq and it works great in C# but i need to convert
the code to vb now and i am not very good at vb.
i have tried using a few of the free online converters and some programs i found but none of them worked, and i tried looking all over on how to do this, but no answer as worked for me so would be great if someone could help me.

the linq part of my code looks like this:

```
var query = from log in wts
            join user in share on log.Substring(51, log.Length - 51).TrimEnd(trim).ToLower() equals user.Substring(0, user.IndexOf("    ")).TrimEnd(trim).ToLower()
            select new { log, user };
foreach (var lognum in query)
{

    lines.Add(lognum.log + lognum.user);
}
```

thank you very much to who helps me.

Edit
i have tried something along the lines of (which i found on the net or in some of the free converters)

```
Dim query = From log In wtsJoin user In share On log.Substring(51, log.Length - 51).TrimEnd(trim).ToLower() = user.Substring(0, user.IndexOf(vbTab)).TrimEnd(trim).ToLower()New From { _
    log, _
    user _
}
For Each lognum As var In query

    lines.Add(lognum.log + lognum.user)
Next
```

Comment: Post the code you have *tried*.

Comment: posted it thank you.

Comment: You can try telerik code converter: http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: @NguyenKien - The Telerik code converter usually makes a mess of Linq conversions as in this case converting equals to `=`, not understanding that `var` is not a keyword in VB and missing out a `Select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Dim query = From log In wts
            Join user In share
            On log.Substring(51, log.Length - 51).TrimEnd(trim).ToLower() Equals user.Substring(0, user.IndexOf(vbTab)).TrimEnd(trim).ToLower()
            Select log & user
```

Or using extension methods

```vb
Dim query = wts.Join(share,
                     Function(log) log.Substring(51, log.Length - 51).TrimEnd(trim).ToLower(),
                     Function(user) user.Substring(0, user.IndexOf(vbTab)).TrimEnd(trim).ToLower(),
                     Function(log, user) log & user)
```

If `lines` in your example is of type `List(Of String)` then convert query to list

```vb
Dim lines As List(Of String) = query.ToList()
```

Comment: If you want the VB code to also have the query return an anonymous type (like the C# query does), then change your 'Select' to "Select New With {Key log, Key user}".